# Python3.5 Error with urlib.request library

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

- This script visits the url specified and outputs the contents into a local file.
- When ans = 1 the script works as intended.
- When ans = 2 the script always returns an error for some reason.
- All help is appreciated. :)

  ```
  import urllib.request

  ans = True

  while ans:
      print("""
        - Menu Selection -
        1. Automatic
        2. Manual
        3. Add 
        4. Exit
        """)

  ans = input('Select Option : ')

  if ans =="1":
      with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.mywebsite.net/something.txt') as response:
        html = response.read()
        f = open('proxylist.txt','a')
        f.write(str(html))
        f.close()
        print('Data saved.')
        ans = True

  if ans =="2":
      input('Enter link : ')
      link = input()
      try:
          with urllib.request.urlopen(link) as response:
             html1 = response.read()
             f = open('proxylist.txt','a+')
             f.write(str(html1))
             f.close()
             print('Data saved.')
             ans = True
      except:
          print('User Input Error')
          ans = True
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to input data twice and ignoring the first result:

```
input('Enter link : ')
link = input()
```

Change that to just:

```
link = input('Enter link : ')
```